# Where does unity go in a multi-project solution?

Tags: c#, unity-container

I'm working on a project with iDesign/Unity and I decided to break this one up so that it is multiple projects. I currently have projects for Controllers, Services, Repositories, and Models, but I'm having trouble figuring out where to put my unity configuration. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You put Unity in the main project only. This is where you **Composition Root** goes, the place you define all app-wide dependencies. Other modules do not reference Unity at all, rather you use some other form of setting up dependencies, for example using the **Local Factory/Dependency Resolver** patterns.

Code examples and thorough explanation in my blog entry

http://www.wiktorzychla.com/2016/01/di-factories-and-composition-root.html

Comment: One follow up question: if I am following the package configuration I gave, that would make the controller the main package right? And so I should put the DI in there? Also, I'm very new to doing multi-package projects and I'm trying to figure out what type of project to make the non main package.

Comment: If this is an asp.net app, the controller assembly is often the main one. But this is not a requirement, but rather an often choice.